# Listing days of week and events on that day (php,mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, date

So, I have a page and I want to list all the days of the week and events on that day for a pub. Some of the days dont have events but i still want to list the day of the week. How should i set this up in my mysql database?

Comment: I tried setting up a table with days of the week (week number, week day) and then a event table with pub id, day_of_week_number, and event) and when I select all with the speicific pub id. it only gets the week days that have the events.

Comment: So if there's no event, just output a blank table cell

Comment: Try posting some of the relevant snippets of code. It's pretty hard to know what you are doing if you don't.

Comment: Use `weekday LEFT JOIN event ON ...`, not `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @ypercube - this wont work because im only selecting events for that pub. so if theres only an event for monday and tuesday, it will get those.

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't know what you are doing wrong. You can edit your question.

Comment: In fact, some could speculate about what you are doing wrong. But some are code addicts and want to see code :)

Comment: this works if i dont specify a pub id...[code]SELECT *
FROM week
LEFT JOIN specials ON week.week_num = specials.day_of_week
LIMIT 0 , 30[/code] but if i do [code]SELECT *
FROM week
LEFT JOIN specials ON week.week_num = specials.day_of_week
WHERE specials.bid = '16381'[/code] it doesnt return null week days

Comment: ok this work... [code]SELECT *
FROM week
LEFT JOIN specials ON (
week.week_num = specials.day_of_week
AND specials.bid = '16381'
)[/code]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    w.week_day
  , e.pub_id
  , e.event
FROM 
    weekday AS w
  LEFT JOIN 
    event AS e
      ON  e.day_of_week_number = w.week_number
      AND e.pub_id = @search_this_pub_id
ORDER BY 
    w.week_number
```